# Remove the long Directory listing in the shell prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to remove the long listing of the current directory in the shell prompt.

Its sometimes annoying when you are using a small shell window and it occupies the whole space in the window

I would rather prefer the just the current directory at the prompt.

> root@Kiran:~/Downloads/Director1/Director2/Director3/Director4#
>   I would prefer something like : 
>   root@Kiran:..Directory4#

or Better even,

> root:Directory4#

Thanks

Comment: The answers below can be found by executing `man bash`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
export PS1='\u:\W\$ '
```

Comment: Although, I like seeing the whole working directory, so I just put a `\n#` at the end of my PS1 line and that moves the cursor down a line.

Comment: What does that Regular Expression do? @Rob: If you are the one that posted this answer and want to get your accounts merged, flag your post for moderator attention and type in the box that you would like to have your accounts migrated. In any case, welcome to Super User! :)

Comment: No, that's not me. the `\n` just puts in a newline mark. I should've said `PS1='\u:\w\n\$ '` That would make the prompt "user:fulldirectory{newline}$ "

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `\W` and not `\w` when you export/set your PS1 variable:

```
export PS1='\u:\h \W #'
```

Answer (score 3):

With Bash version 4+ you can set

```
export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1
```

in your .bashrc. The prompt for a non-root user:

```
user@host:~/.../dir>
```

and for root

```
host:.../dir #
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick in addition to the ones above is too put a newline near the end of your prompt (\n$) so that what you type has the full length of the terminal:

```
mattb@flat:~/.../work_notes/admin
$
```

From my ~/.bashrc:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    # the \n\$ at the end puts the prompt on a newline
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi

# I don't want a huge path on display
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
```